# .htaccess IP Blocking not working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, block

I can't seem to get this .htaccess IP blocking script to work. I want to block any IP except mine from being able to access the wordpress login script and admin folder. My IP is 55.55.555.55 in this code. It works in that it blocks access to the file and folder from all IP's, but it doesn't let me access it through my IP. I get the 403 error as well. I am running Cloudflare, I don't know if that could be causing problems. Here is the current .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Block everyone but me
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^55\.55\.555\.55$
RewriteRule ^(wp-login\.php|wp-admin) - [F,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I don't know why it isn't working, I've tried half a dozen variations of the wordpress login .htaccess IP blocker, and the IP is my actual IP, the IP it showed on 5 different 'What's my IP' sites. When I delete or rename the .htaccess, anyone can view the login page, but when it's there I can't either.

Also, the blog itself is in blog.domain.com, domain.com does a 301 redirect to take it there, so the blog and .htaccess are in blog.domain.com/. I doubt that makes a difference, but that's how it's set up.

Update: I tried using the same .htaccess on another site I have, which doesn't have cloudflare, here is the .htaccess I used

```
AddHandler php-stable .php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Block everyone but me
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^55\.55\.555\.55$
RewriteRule ^(index.php) - [F,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

As you can see, I changed it to only work on the index.php, and I made a quick test index.php page. When I went there on my computer, it loads it, but proxies return the 403 correctly. Could cloudflare somehow be causing the problems? Even though I disabled the caching, could it be screwing with it?

I just found this https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads#mod_cloudflare I'm reading it now

Answer (score 0):

Order of rules in .htaccess is very important. In your case WP rules are above and taking full control.

Change order or the rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Block everyone but me
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^55\.55\.555\.55$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(wp-login\.php|wp-admin/)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# regular WP stuff
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: I still get a 403 when I try to go there with that. The IP is right, I triple checked. It still blocks other IP's as well, not just mine.

Comment: I tried that and variations of that and it doesn't seem to fix it. I disabled cloudflare caching on the server as well. I have a 301 redirect that the domain takes to blog.domain.com, so all of the wordpress files including this .htaccess are in blog.domain.com if that makes a difference. I'll put the full current .htaccess in the original post.

Comment: I made another edit, please test it. If doesn't work then post your existing .htaccess in question.

Comment: The .htaccess of your newest one doesn't work either. I'm going to add some more details about what I found out in the original post

Comment: Are you sure you're using `RewriteRule ^(wp-login\.php|index\.php|wp-admin) - [F,NC]` line in your rule?

Comment: @MikeShaw: Made an important edit, I believe it should work now.